# $.ajax only working in Safari - probably something with request

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, request

the following script seems to work only in Safari

```
function getPictures() {
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "getimages.php",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml) {
                alert('success');
            }

    });
}
```

getimages.php dynamically creates xml content via PHP.

I read that this problem might have something to do with needing a request. I've never worked with Ajax in any way and don't have time to do research.

How do I have to change this script so it works in as many browsers as possible?

The XML output of the PHP file looks like this

```
    <image url="MY_IMAGE_URL_1.jpg" number="1">
    <image url="MY_IMAGE_URL_2.jpg" number="2">
    <image url="MY_IMAGE_URL_3.jpg" number="3">
    <image url="MY_IMAGE_URL_4.jpg" number="4">
```

etc.

I would have thought the success function will be called when the file is loaded regardless of it's content

Comment: Your code is OK so i guess the problem is in response with not valid xml. I suggest to check it or give as an example

Comment: JQuery is designed to be compatible in most browsers. Do you get any JavaScript errors?

Comment: you should include error: function(errorThrown, textStatus, jqXHR) { console.log(errorThrown) }.  Place this after the success property seperated by a comma. Then check your browsers console when you run the script to see what errors you have.

Comment: Have you tried using a tool like Fiddler to watch the web request in other browsers? I don't see any reason why this script wouldn't work, unless getimages.php is throwing an error or potentially generated invalid XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should add an `error` event handler in your AJAX request:

```
function getPictures() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "getimages.php",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function(req, status) {
            alert(status);
        }
    });
}
```

Second, you need to close all the elements in your XML (ending them with `/>`) as well as wrap them in a containing element as there [can only be one root element in XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-well-formed):

```
<images>
    <image url="MY_IMAGE_URL_1.jpg" number="1" />
    <image url="MY_IMAGE_URL_2.jpg" number="2" />
    <image url="MY_IMAGE_URL_3.jpg" number="3" />
    <image url="MY_IMAGE_URL_4.jpg" number="4" />
</images>
```

Answer (score 4):

Your XML is malformed.

Add `/` to close the tags.

```
<image url="MY_IMAGE_URL_1.jpg" number="1" />
<image url="MY_IMAGE_URL_2.jpg" number="2" />
<image url="MY_IMAGE_URL_3.jpg" number="3" />
<image url="MY_IMAGE_URL_4.jpg" number="4" />
```

Comment: I fixed the XML but success still won't be called